# show tooltip onmouse over near the image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tooltip

I want to show the tooltip on mouse over the image in a table. Please find the sample fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/FpBu4/42/
I want to display the tooltip on the right top of the image on mouse over.
Below is the sample script:

```
$('.one').hover(function(ev){
    $('.tooltipSample').stop(true,true).fadeIn(); 
},function(ev){
    $('.tooltipSample').stop(true,true).fadeOut();
}).mousemove(function(ev){
    $('.tooltipSample').css({left:ev.layerX+10,top:ev.layerY+10});
});
```

Please suggest how to show the tooltip near the image on mouse over the image. Thanks.

Comment: Here is a good tooltip sample http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/

Answer (score 2):

Add `position:absolute;` to the `tooltipSample` and use `pageX` and `pageY` instead of `layerX` and `layerY`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FpBu4/43/)

Answer (score 0):

Please note, I have not tested this. However, in a recent project I worked on, I had to dynamically add a new div close to a control. What I did was add the new div to the control's parent.

Possibly you could do something like this:

```
$('.one').parent().hover(function(ev){...});
```

Just a thought and maybe someone else may have a better solution